# Displaying a random number into a Textfield using jFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

How would I display a random number into a text field on jFrame? My method for generating a random number is in a different class.

```
Random rn = new Random(); 
    int i = rn.nextInt(51);
    System.out.println(i);
```

How would I make the number appear in the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a seperate class.

Just do as following.

```
Random rn = new Random(); 
JTextField textField = //initialize your text field here
```

Then set the random number as,

```
textField.setText(Integer.toString(rn.nextInt(51)));
```